# Strange scrolling of UITableView while scrolling and cell height change are executed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

I have a UITableView with a lot of cells. On the cells that have a UITextField i scroll the table if the keyboard would hide the textfield. And to some cells i added a change of cell height to the scroll.
This works fine at the beginning and middle of the table but if the cell in question is at the bottom of the table I am getting some strange jumping around and vanishing of cells.
After the user has finished the editing the height of the cell is changed back to normal and the vanished cells reappear but the table is scrolled a bit upwards.
My question is now how can I get rid of this jumping and vanishing of cells?

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if fieldIndex != [-99, -99] {
        if indexPath.section == fieldIndex[0] && indexPath.row == fieldIndex[1] {
            fieldIndex = [-99, -99]
            return 220.0
        }
    }
    return 80.0
}

func keyboardWillBeShown(_ sender: Notification) {
    let info: NSDictionary = (sender as NSNotification).userInfo! as NSDictionary
    let value: NSValue = info.value(forKey: UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
    let keyboardSize: CGSize = value.cgRectValue.size
    let height = toolBar.frame.height
    let contentInset: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height + toolBar.frame.height + 60, 0.0)
    originalIntersect = tableView.contentInset
    tableView.contentInset = contentInset
    tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInset

    var aRect: CGRect = self.view.frame
    aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.height
}

func keyboardWillBeHidden(_ sender: Notification) {
    let insets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.tableView.contentInset.top, 0, 0, 0)
    tableView.contentInset = originalIntersect
    tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = originalIntersect
}
```

If there is other code you need to see to help just ask.

Regards and Thanks
Adarkas

Comment: Why do you change the height of the cells in order to accommodate the displacement due to the keyboard? why not add a constraint to the bottom of the UITableView and set it to the height of the keyboard, and then scroll to the last cell within the tableView?

Comment: The height change is due to a dropdown-list with the ability to search in the cells where i change the height.